# how to select substring in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

in idSoal table have id : 1201532,1201533,1201632,1201633 , 
the code :

```
 <select name="YEAR">
            <option value="">Pilih tahun ajaran</option>
            <?php
            include 'connect.php';
            $sql="SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(idSoal,1,4) AS tahun FROM hasiljwb ;";
            $hasil= mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($hasil)){

            echo '<option value="' . $row['tahun'] . '">' . $row['tahun']  . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
 </select>
```

i just want get value 2015 and 2016, how to fix this code?

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(idSoal,2,4) AS tahun FROM hasiljwb";
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: if i want add slash in lash character of $row['tahun'] how do it? so that it result is 2015/2016